# elasticsearch dynamic templates don't match "deep" properties

Tags: templates, dynamic, elasticsearch, mapping

I started to look into creating a specific ES-mapping for tweets, but quickly realized that an ES-mapping of the tweet-model would become a nightmare to maintain over time so I started to think about dynamic templates. I've registered a dynamic template for every possible property according to the twitter object description. A tweet is a very hierarchical and redundant format which means that a property, say "created_at", may be present at a number of places - thus the nightmare to maintain a stable explicit mapping.

In the mapping I've created so far I have **no** explicit mappings ("properties"-attribute is empty) as I want **all** the mappings to be controlled by dynamic templates. As an example my dynamic template for the "created_at" property looks like:

```
{
    "created_at": {
    "match": "created_at",
    "mapping": {
        "format": "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z YYYY",
        "index": "no"
    }
}
```

I thought that having this template would take care of the mapping of a "created_at" property whereever it would appear in the json-structure. I know that I may specify "path_match" in order to explicitly specify a give property-instance but I want **all** the "created_at" attributes to be mapped according to the template above.

However - when I start indexing data into ES I get numerous errors looking something like:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: unknown property [created_at]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper.parseCreateFieldForString(StringFieldMapper.java:331)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper.parseCreateField(StringFieldMapper.java:277)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:399)
    ... 13 more
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try adding `"match_mapping_type": "*"` to the `created_at` template and see how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following example to set up a dynamic template:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_for_created_at -d '
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic": true,
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "created_at_tmpl": {
            "match": "created_at",
            "match_mapping_type": "date",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z YYYY",
              "index": "no",
              "null_value": null
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

More details and examples can be found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm soo sorry I haven't marked this question as "solved"!!!! I managed to get it working after some investigations. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Cheers